# Behavior of Parse.saveEventually when called from a service

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm just getting started with Parse on android, and I stumbled upon the saveEventually functionality. I will be calling all of the 'save' methods from a broadcast intent receiver, rather than from an activity upon user action. The nature of the app is such that the user does not have to open the app at all for using it, it's intended to be a background service. In such a scenario where the application is never manually  opened, after except for the first time, will the 'saveEventually' actually work the way it should (i.e that is automatically saving it when there is access to internet)? My worry rises from the fact that the Parse documentation says: "If your app is closed before the connection is back, Parse will try again the next time the app is opened."

Comment: Did you ever find an answer, official or empirical?